# Error en estructura reCaptcha y formulario PHP

Tags: php, html, formularios, recaptcha

Tengo un formulario en HTML que es validado a través de PHP con reCaptcha. El problema es que la estructura del else no responde correctamente y no se recíbe el mensaje al correo electrónico.

```
  <?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$asunto = $_POST['subject'];
$mensaje = $_POST['message'];
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$secret = "secretkey******************";

if (!$captcha) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Por favor verifica el captcha...');</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='index.html#work';</script>";
}

 $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha");
 $arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);
 var_dump($response);
 if($arr['succes']){
     
     //Inicia código de formulario
     $destinatario = 'myemail@mail';
     $header = "Enviado desde el Sitio Web";
     $mensajeCompleto = $mensaje . "\nDe: " . $nombre;

     mail($nombre, $email, $asunto, $mensaje, $mensajeCompleto, $header);

     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('¡Tu mensaje ha sido enviado exitosamente!');</script>";
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='index.html#work';</script>";
     //Termina código de formulario
     
    }else{
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('¡¡¡Error al comprobar  captcha!!!');</script>";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='index.html#work';</script>";
    }
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué información te muestra el var_dump?

Comment: Hola. Por la estructura que muestras parece que esperas que se mostrase alguno de los `alert()` ¿Se ejecuta alguno?

Comment: @quevedo ¡¡¡Error al comprobar captcha!!!

Comment: @Luis Alfredo Serrano Díaz  {"success":true, "challenge_ts":"fecha":"hostname":"dominio del sitio"}"

Comment: En el volcado que haces de `var_dump($response)` se evidencia la presencia una clave `'success'` y no **succes *que es la que estás verificando***. Luego de corregir ese *typo* pensamos en otros detalles.

Comment: @quevedo la observación de ''success'' funcionó ya que ahora valida el captcha correctamente, pero sigue sin mandarse el correo.

Comment: Queda pendiente un detalle. Vi que ya ajustaste el paso de parámetros a mail(). Pero, en tu código se sugiere que envías texto plano. Si por casualidad piensas enviarlo como html, en el ejemplo 4 de la documentación [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail) se ilustra el formato requerido por loas cabeceras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He corregido **succes** por **success** y he cambiado el orden de los encabezados al siguiente:

```
mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensajeCompleto, $header);
```